# Creating a simple GUI that asks for inputs, that then run a script

Tags: python, user-interface, input

I have a script in python, but now I am trying to have a GUI interface that has some text boxes that a user can fill in values to some variables, and then click 'run' to run the script.

What would the easiest way to approach this be?

Thanks a ton

Comment: one of the easiest ways would be using TkInter.

Comment: `PyQt` is a powerful and popular cross-platform GUI library. The tutorial is nice to start with https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/index.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create GUI in python there are lots of packages available. I am using one of them (given below):

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

text_box = Entry(master)
text_box.pack()

text_box.focus_set()

def callback():
    print text_box.get()

button = Button(master, text="ok", width=10, command=callback)
button.pack()
mainloop()
```

It will print input text given by user on terminal.